# get/check inner kernel32 state for process win32 (for safe usage of TerminateThread )

Tags: c++, winapi, thread-safety, threadpool, kernel32

I've written a threadpool with a terminate option for threads available to the user. As described in
[Documentation of API `terminateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread),

> If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be inconsistent.

I could verify this problem myself: Terminating a thread in that condition caused memory allocation  problems (amongst others), but fixing that condition fixed the problems at the same time.

### Questions

1. So, I want to check this inner state after every time `terminateThread()` has been used. If `terminateThread()` has caused problem for the inner state of a process in kernel32.dll, I want to raise an exception - and terminate the process after logging to user (unless fixing the inner state is still possible).

   Is this feasible? Maybe by finding the address of the relevant state variable (or anything like that - by matching the pdb file of kernel32 or another way)? The situation is bad for me - if I cannot solve it, I either have to omit the terminate option for the threapool or just leave the thread for itself. Any hints would be appreciated!
2. Is there any other win32 function that causes similar problems?
3. a. Is it safe to leave a thread for itself when it has called a blocking kernel32 function that will definitely never return?

   b. What happens if the win32 function returns and the lambda function has been destroyed?

### Why am I asking this? (Supplementary information)

I have a custom threadpool in my project where I call some win32 APIs that may sometimes block forever. Hence, I call them using a timeout. When that timeout is reached, I call `terminateThread()` and have my threadpool return "unsucessfull call state".

Sometimes, my current app reaches a deadlock. I found out that this deadlock is happening in the threadpool, so I'm looking for alternatives to `terminateThread()` (such as leaving the thread as I described in the question) or trying to fix the inner state, or at least to verify whether `terminateThread()` is the root of my deadlock.

I'd like to reuse this threadpool in other projects, too, so I should make it safe.

### Update: Problem fixed.

I found the bug in my app:
It was actually a call to `terminateThread()` when the timeout in my threadpool was already low (about 200 ms).
The thread was killed in a moment when it wasn't blocking (i.e., if a longer timeout period had remained, it would have worked and returned correctly).
From the kernel stack trace I found out that in kernel mode, a mutex was being locked while the thread was terminated, and while the thread was exiting, other threads were already waiting for that mutex.

The problem first appeared to go away by increasing the minimum timeout to 1000 ms, but I wasn't content with that:
My solution was to create lambda on heap when timeout reached, to leave the lambda and the thread for itself without terminating, and to add it to a list of `_ToTerminateThreads`.
The list gets terminated once in 10 minutes (waits 10 min., copies the list, waits another minute, and then terminates the threads and deletes the lambdas).

Still, after testing and hours of debugging I was getting heap corruptions.
Finally I found out the following:
The threads that I had left for deletion
wrote to the memory that had been used by the user function (which was passed to threadpool)
- and they were freed because threadpool had returned.
This had caused the ultimate problems, so the final solution was to increase the timeout to a safe amount.

I recommend to everyone who needs such a feature to deploy it to a child process, and to terminate that process instead of using a thread.

I keep this question open because the main 4 questions haven't been answered  yet. For my problem, I don't need their answer anymore, but they may be interesting for other members of stackoverflow.

Comment: More reading - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=91811

Comment: When you terminate a thread, you cannot do *anything* meaningful anymore. The process has entered a state from which it cannot recover. Trying to check conditions after the fact isn't going to be a solution. Maybe you should ask about the *real* problem you are trying to solve. It has become clear, that there is an issue with your code that's not related to the thread pool at all.

Comment: @IInspectable well i have custom threadpool in my project, i call some win32 APIs that sometimes block for ever, so i call using a timeout, when timeout is reached , i call terminatethread , and return "unsecessfull call state" from my threadpool ,currently sometimes my app reaches a deadlock , i found out that this deadlock is happening in the threadpool ,so i'm looking for alternative for terminatethread (like leaving it as said in question) or checking fixing the inner state , or atleast verify the terminatethread is the root of my deadlock

Comment: Can you give a few examples of the _"...some win32 APIs that sometimes block for ever..."_ please?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)? As for verification of your code being the cause of your deadlock, that's pretty straight forward. Your process is in a state, where it doesn't make forward progress. At that point, fire up Task Manager, and have it gather a mini dump. Load that up in a debugger, like WinDbg, and check for wait cycles. WinDbg has the convenient [`!locks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-locks---kdext--locks-) extension for this.

Comment: Also make sure to consider this: [Must be This Tall to Write Multi-Threaded Code](https://bholley.net/images/posts/thistall.jpg) (link to [article](https://bholley.net/blog/2015/must-be-this-tall-to-write-multi-threaded-code.html)).

Comment: no any *inner state* and you not need use terminate thread.

Comment: Could you show some related code or stack trace of deadlock following steps pointed by @IInspectable's ?

Comment: @RichardCritten like NtQueryObject  when quering name some randome handles , or any external bad coded driver with does block sometimes ,,, actually the page you linked helped my figure this out .thx for that

Comment: @IInspectable avoiding something because it's difficult is bullshit ( the "must be this tall to write multi threaded code") , you need to try to get that tall, it doesn't come by magic.....sure i had taken many dumps and debugging htem before creating a question on stackoverflow

Comment: @RbMm you are officially denying the msdn documentation

Comment: @ema: You didn't get the point. The point is, that multithreaded code in C or C++ isn't just difficult to verify to be correct. It is **impossible** to verify to be correct. You'd need to choose a different programming language if you needed that guarantee. And this question you indicates, that you are in dire need of language support to prove correctness.

Comment: @emaditaj -what you mean more concrete ?

Comment: @RbMm you said there is no inner state , the quote from MSDN in beginning  of my post says there is

Comment: @emaditaj what you mean under *inner state* ?

Comment: @RbMm "the kernel32 state" i meant "inner kernel32 state for my process", i don't know what it actually is , the msdn mentioned it in the quote

Comment: @emaditaj - if you dont know - how you can write about you dont know ? no any "inner state". you not need use terminatethread. you need found and fix errors in your code

Comment: @RbMm as wrote in the update, i found and fixed the errors in my code , and terminatethread was root of it , you have any solution for calling an external function that may block for ever? i could only think of running in separate thread and terminating after timeout ... if i knew what exactly it is, i could find a solution to check it myself  didn't need to make a question about it , and for existence of the the inner state ,msdn says it exists (or mayby i'm reading it badly ).. anyway let's finish this story of comments, the problem is already solved  and thanks for your contirbution

Comment: @emaditaj Glad to hear the issue solved. You can answer your own question by post an answer and accept it.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT done that , thanks for reading this post

Comment: @IInspectable thanks got it, you know any language that has that guarantee? i first tried to write my code using c#, but it was way worse (because of the CLR treadpool and limits of the language compared with c++) (i don't what to rewrite, i finished the project, just asking out of curiosity)

Comment: @ema: [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).

Comment: @emaditaj - Reading the Q&A with little capitalisation and quite long sentences isn't very easy. I chose to propose an edit. Please check if the re-written version still describes your question and report correctly (which I believe it does, but you never know). I hope this helps other readers to make use of this Q&A.

Comment: @HelpingHand thanks for your edit and time, i approved it

Comment: @emaditaj - You're welcome. I prepared the same kind of thing for your self-answer, but the edit queue is full all the time :(   **Edit:** Now it worked out...

Comment: @HelpingHand thanks , i did aproved and it made it much more easy to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue resolved although it has nothing to do with 3 questions in post.
I try to answer them in reverse order:

- **ad 3.b.)** If an external function returns and your local lambda has been deleted, the cpu won't know this and will try to process the bytes at that offset as CPU instructions. This surely will mess you up, so never do that!
- **ad 3.a.)** Yes, it is safe to leave if you're 100% sure the external function will never return (otherwise it'll mess your app when return

  1. if you deleted the rest of the code with the same way explained in **b.**
  2. if you haven't deleted the lambda or it's a gobal function, it'll run the rest of function which may be editing dynamic allocated memories (heap, not stack) which has been deallocated and cause heap corruption or simply just edit some global variables).
- **ad 2.)** I googled for dangerous winapi functions and didn't find any result other than `TerminateThread()`.
  If you know about one, please add a comment or write another answer.
- **ad 1.)** I don't have any solution for checking/fixing the inner kernel32 state for the process that Microsoft refers to.
  I think a guy at Microsoft who has read kernel32.dll source code should answer this.

Apart from this kernel32 state, `TerminateThread()` will cause lots of other problems (like resource/heap allocations, mutex locks, leaks and so on) so never use it unless you 100% sure what you are doing.

Read the article @RichardCritten linked in the comments: [`TerminateThread()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=91811)

### What was the bug in my code?

I was calling `TerminateThread()` with a low timeout (300 ms).
Randomly when a machine had low resources, the function was still operating (I mean non-blocking call!).
I terminated that function and thereby caused a kernel mutex to be locked.
This locked mutex made all other threads wait - and not exit when they returned.

### Remarks

I answered my own question from what I found after I didn't receive any answer. Hence, it may contain some wrong information. Please correct me if anything is wrong in this.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT did it, can you please upvote my question , i can't create any new question because  some of my old questions includeing this have zero or negative vote

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-cant-i-ask-questions-on-stackoverflow) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251113/i-cant-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow) for "providing one or two more quality answers that get upvoted" or "editing for improving your questions". ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Hope this helps.